# Probability that at least one suit is missing in a player's hand

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here's an interesting problem from Henk Tijms's *Understanding Probability*.

> What is the probability that in a player's hand of 13 cards at least
>   one suit will be missing?

My approach is applying the inclusion-exclusion rule:

$$
P(\text{one suit missing})=\binom{4}{1}\left(\frac14\right)^{13}-\binom{4}{2}\left(\frac12\right)^{13}+\binom{4}{3}\left(\frac34\right)^{13}\simeq 0.0943
$$
where the first term on the rhs counts the probability that the player's hand consists of 13 cards of the same suit, the second term counts the probability that the hand contains cards from at most two suits, and the third term is the probability that the player's hand consists of at most three suits.

However, the book gives the result $0.051$, so something is wrong in my solution.

Comment: Your calculation gives the probability if the cards are dealt *with replacement*, which is not how cards are normally dealt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_i = \{ \text { Suit } i \text{ is missing  } \} $. By inclusion-exclusion we have: $$P (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4) =  \frac {\binom41 \cdot \binom {39}{13}}{\binom {52}{13}} - \frac {\binom42 \cdot \binom {26}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}} + \frac {\binom43 \cdot 1}{\binom {52}{13}} = 0.051 $$

Comment: I see, so the problem is that I cannot count the number of hands missing $i$ suits with $\left(\frac{4-i}{4}\right)^{13}$? What is wrong in this way of thinking?

Comment: Note that if one suit is missing. Then, we cannot deal with the 13 cards of that suit. We then have to choose 13 cards from the 39 cards remaining. There are then $\binom {39}{13} $ ways to select.

Comment: Note if two suits are missing, we follow the same reasoning.

Comment: Now I understand. So the formula $\left(\frac{4-i}{4}\right)^{13}$ does not count the fact that as the drawing of cards proceeds, the probability of getting a card of a given suit differs from $1/4$. This is why the geometric distribution is used instead.